# Can't connect to Linode using ssh

Tags: networking, ssh

Trying to connect from Ubuntu 22.04 through `ssh` to linode. But it's giving:

```
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xxx port 22: No route to host
```

I tried ping xx.xx.xx.xxx and it worked fine. Output of telnet xx.xx.xx.xxx:

```
Trying xx.xx.xx.xxx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

Additionally, I ensured that my SSH public key located at `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` had been added to the Linode's list of authorized SSH keys.